# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS over heating

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, acer, fan, overheating

I have dual booted both the windows 10 & ubuntu 20.04 in the SSD (512GB). I have noticed that while using ubuntu fan speed is very high & system gets over heat even when few software are running. But while using windows did not noticed much heat or any of these issues.. Battery usage also windows provides much better in comparing to ubutnu..

[Laptop spec](https://store.acer.com/en-in/acer-aspire-5-a515-56-thin-light):

Acer Aspire 5 Thin And Light Laptop Intel Core I5 11th Gen (8GB/512Gb SSD/Windows 10 Home/NVIDIA® GeForce® MX350 ) A515-56G With 39.6cm FHD Display/1.7kgs

Top screenshot:
[image: screenshot of top command that shows google-chrome with 1.7% CPU usage and skypeforlinux at 0.7% and a handful of other processes using 0.3% each]

Please help.. ask for any additional info in the comments.

Screenshot from i7z:
[image]

Comment: your `top` screenshot does not show anything unusual. How much is "too hot". have you run `sensors`?

Comment: I also had overheating issues but I noticed that my fans were running slower than in windows. I tried using custom drivers to increase fan speed but kind of failed. Eventually, I switched to arch.

Comment: By the way, are you using the proprietary Nvidia drivers available directly from the official Ubuntu repos?

Comment: Also, you can get the intel temperature by installing and running the i7z command:  `sudo apt udpate` then `sudo apt install i7z` and finally `sudo i7z`

Comment: @mchid Yes i am using the nvidia driver, while installing ubuntu, i had choose to use the recommended graphic driver. Now attached the temp from i7z.

Comment: @Bruni Attached the screenshot of temp from i7z.

Answer (score 0):

I get some pretty brutal debugging about chrome browser, it goes on indefinitely and I'm thinking of giving up using chrome altogether.
Look in the log `journalctl -b-0 -g error`, maybe you have a similar situation with it.

In addition, I still don't fully understand why I need `debug.exception-trace=1`, because I'm not a developer and it consumes too much energy.
On a device as weak as mine, this is very noticeable (and causes the algorithms to fail).
Try disabling it. I delivered it a value of 0, and my machine is now as cold as a sheet of paper.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try this & update you

Comment: Well, try it out and also you can see how it can be used here `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml`, I put the pid-based code here. Now I can easily adjust the temperature based on getting the pid number for Intel device. You can also configure it based on the processor data, using this output; `for i in /sys/class/thermal/cooling*; do echo "$i: $(<$i/type)"; done`.

Comment: But basically all my problems with using Ubuntu were related to the failure of the algorithms, when I accelerated the device all my problems disappeared, I do not report errors because I have no questions or errors )