# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS machine heating

Tags: dual-boot, power-management, battery, fan, overheating

I am Using **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** Machine with dual booting

I have dual-booted both windows 10 & ubuntu 20.04 in the SSD (250GB). I have noticed that while using ubuntu fan speed is very high & the system gets overheat even when few software are running. But while using windows did not notice much heat or any of these issues. Battery usage also windows provides much better in comparing to ubuntu.

Terminal-**Sensors**
[image]

Terminal->**hardinfo**[image]

***My Laptop Spec***

- Ram->20GB
- Processor->Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @1.60GHz

I show a Similar question But I didn't get an answer to my question [Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS over heating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322455/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-over-heating).

Comment: check kernel logs, see what top says is running